# request method 'POST' not supported 405

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

on submitting my form i get an

```
 Response Status: 405 (Method Not Allowed) Cause:
 org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException Request
 method 'POST' not supported
```

and i have no idea why.

Controller:

```
RequestMapping("/mymapping")
public class MyController extends AbstractController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/myformtest/{taskId}", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public String functionone(@PathVariable("taskId") String taskId, Model model, Locale locale, Authentication authentication) {
 dosomething...
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myformtest/{taskId} ", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public String functiontwo(@PathParam("taskId") String taskId,
        @ModelAttribute("myObject") MyObject myObject,
        @ModelAttribute("taskAction") String taskAction,
        Model model, Locale locale, Authentication authentication) {
 dosomething...
}
}

<form id="myform" action="#" class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator" method="POST" role="form"  th:object="${myObject}">

</form>

<button type="button" value="FORWARD" class="btn btn-success submitBtn" th:text="#{mytext}"></button>    

$('.submitBtn').click(function() {
  $('#taskAction').val($(this).attr("value"));
  $("#myform").attr('action', $("#taskId").val());
  $("#myform").submit();
});
```

i start with localhost:8888/mymapping/myformtest/123 -> works fine
i click on the button, the browser goes to localhost:8888/mymapping/myformtest/123 ->

```
405 (Method Not Allowed) 'POST' not supported
```

any idea why?

Comment: A suggestion for this code.  You should use `@GetMapping("/myformtest/{taskId}")` and `@PostMapping("/myformtest/{taskId}")` for this.

Answer (score 0):

i found the bug. there was a space in the RequestMapping at the post methode.

Comment: ok but don't correct the question. That way it is harder to understand for ppl coming coming here later.